# Problems for join arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem but my brain doesn't give for more. I have this code

```
$pedidosper    = new PedidosPer();
$salidapedidos = $pedidosper->salidaPedidos();

$productosBloqueados = new PedidosPer();
$productosBloqueados = $productosBloqueados->salidaPedidosBloqueados();

$newArray  = [];
$newArray2 = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < \count($salidapedidos); ++$i) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < \count($productosBloqueados); ++$j) {
        if ($salidapedidos[$i]->id_order == $productosBloqueados[$j]->idOrder) {
            $newArray[] = [
                $salidapedidos[$i]->id_order, 
                $salidapedidos[$i]->name_shop, 
                $salidapedidos[$i]->payment, 
                $salidapedidos[$i]->customer_firstname,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->customer_lastname, 
                $salidapedidos[$i]->reference, 
                $salidapedidos[$i]->total, 
                $salidapedidos[$i]->fecha, 
                $productosBloqueados[$j]->estado_id, 
            ];
        }
    }
    $newArray2[] = [
        $salidapedidos[$i]->id_order, 
        $salidapedidos[$i]->name_shop, 
        $salidapedidos[$i]->payment, 
        $salidapedidos[$i]->customer_firstname,
        $salidapedidos[$i]->customer_lastname, 
        $salidapedidos[$i]->reference, 
        $salidapedidos[$i]->total, 
        $salidapedidos[$i]->fecha, 
        '', 
        ];
}
```

I explain quickly, I am making a query to a database A and then I make the query to a database B. Database A and B share similar data and I am extracting the data to form a final array with the data that will be displayed on the screen.

As you can see this is the $newArray I make a comparison to create an array that has the data of the first "for" and add the data of the second "for" the idea is to complement the data. The $newArray this great has the data I need.

But now you will see the $newArray2 my idea is that $newArray2 has all the data except the ones that already exist in the $ newArray, at this moment, $newArray2 is placing data that already exists in $newArray but that I no longer want to have there. And the truth is that I don't know what the hell I'm missing. I would be very grateful if you could guide me.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I think all you need to do is put the `$newArray2` inside an ELSE, not outside the for loop

Comment: Hi, thank u for you observation, i make indentation right now. Your solution don't work for me. Bacause this create a array with double data.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `$newarray2` loading to an else inside the loop, then anything that is not placed into the `$newArray` will be put into `$newArray2`

```
$pedidosper          = new PedidosPer();
$salidapedidos       = $pedidosper->salidaPedidos();
$productosBloqueados = new PedidosPer();
$productosBloqueados = $productosBloqueados->salidaPedidosBloqueados();

$newArray  = [];
$newArray2 = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < \count($salidapedidos); ++$i) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < \count($productosBloqueados); ++$j) {
        if ($salidapedidos[$i]->id_order == $productosBloqueados[$j]->idOrder) {
            $newArray[] = [
                $salidapedidos[$i]->id_order,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->name_shop,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->payment,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->customer_firstname,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->customer_lastname,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->reference,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->total,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->fecha,
                $productosBloqueados[$j]->estado_id,
            ];
        } else {
            $newArray2[] = [
                $salidapedidos[$i]->id_order,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->name_shop,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->payment,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->customer_firstname,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->customer_lastname,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->reference,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->total,
                $salidapedidos[$i]->fecha, '',
            ];
        }
    }
}
```